# PHP cURL removes the fragment after the hashmark

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a scenario where I query for links from a database of which some of the URL's have #tags along with it. Like http://example.com/about.html#page2. When I run a PHP cURL on all these queried URL's I'm actually getting cURL result for http://example.com/about.html but not http://example.com/about.html#page2. My current program after the cURL part, searches the table using the URL that the cURL provides which is http://example.com/about.html, an entry of which doesnot exists in the database.

My table have links like this :

http://example.com/about.html#page1

http://example.com/about.html

http://example.com/new.html#something

How can I improve this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. CURL is not a browser and will not run Javascript code. Your hashmark is useless because it's only usefull for the browser to move the scrollbar to a specific position OR to be read via javascript code.

Comment: The reason why I am storing a URL along with the #fragment is all together a requirement for my application. I can't avoid that, so I have to adopt my cURL based function that checks these URL's. Obviously, its correct that CURL is not a browser. So I have to find a workaround solution using the Database/Queries !!! Thats what I am looking for. Thanks for you answer ! Appreciate that !

Comment: Everything behind the hashtag is never sent to the server. Why can't u avoid the url fragments?

Comment: For ex. In my website I have an a label which says Privacy and a link that redirects to the privacy part. For ex: http://example.com/about.html#privacy. Its an integral part my application. So it does not make any sense later if I remove all #fragments from my URL's.

Comment: What do u mean with redirect? U just used a named anchor or you are loading new data with ajax based on it?